# How to detect base of pulse signal

Tags: algorithm, time-series, signal-processing

I have time series range from 0 to 10 as in the picture. The sample data is [here](https://gist.github.com/elcolie/493c013b998a8cfa26d46c3101bf73fe).

I have try moving average, standard deviation in the moving window, but it does not get me the luck to detect base of the pulse I need. I manually put black X markers in the figure to show my interesting points.

How to process this time series?

[image]

Comment: Why not try a median filter?

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11033

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you. It flatten my pulse when I increase `kernel_size`. It is ok at certain point.

Comment: why not ignore/remove pulses that are shorter than some threshold?

Comment: @Spektre Some noise has high amplitude same as signal.

Comment: I mean shorter in time duration not amplitude ...

Answer (score 0):

I use [find_peaks()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) with prominence=10 and width=10 as magic numbers. This partially accepted answer because it has voodoo variable in it.

```py
peaks, props = find_peaks(p_array, prominence=10, width=100)
plt.plot(prediction_array, color='orange', label='predicted label')
plt.scatter(peaks, pp_array[peaks], marker='x', color='red')
plt.scatter([props["left_bases"][0], props["right_bases"][0]], [0, 0], marker='x', color='red', label="width=10,prominence=100")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
```

[image]